# Need to show annotated PDF file using PdfRenderer

Tags: android, pdfrenderer, android-pdf-api

I need to show annotated PDF file using PdfRenderer.
When I try to display annotated PDF using PdfRenderer, annotated part/layer gets missing.

Actually I am displaying PDF files(1st page only) in ViewPager and 3rd party library are not suitable for it. That's why I am using PdfRenderer.

Any help or guidance will be very helpful.